# Is there a reliable way to know whether a request is in an Ajax context in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

I need to deal with these two cases differently,is there a good solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest') { /* ajax request */ }
```

Comment: it's reliable and pretty standard.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of 2 ways to accomplish this:

- On the AJAX side you could set a custom HTTP header with [`XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader()) and then check for the presence of that header on the PHP side with [`getallheaders()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php) to indicate that the request was made by an AJAX client. If your php script doesn't find the custom header, you can consider it to be a non-AJAX request.
- When you create the request in your code, you could simply tack on a querystring variable to indicate the nature of the request. eg. http://example.com/process?ajax=true for an AJAX reqeust or http://example.com/process?ajax=false for a non-AJAX request.